# Role Search Command Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

i have been looking for a command that allowes me to search for role that includes a string
Example would be !findrole Staff, then the command would list all the roles that includes staff, i have not gotten any code to work so please help me

Answer (score 0):

We could do that by creating a map of all roles that include the argument we've entered. We could do so by getting a guild's full roles collection, then filter out the ones we really need and return all of the ones we find into a map of our choice. I've personally come up with the following code:

```
    let roleCheck = ''
    const role = args.join(' ')
    const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.filter(r => {
        roleCheck = r.name.includes(role)
        return roleCheck
    }).map(role => {
        return role.name
    })

    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${role} Roles List`)
        .setDescription(`\`${roles.join('\n')}\``)
        .setColor(3426654)
    message.channel.send(Embed)
```